# How to set a constraint using percentage?

Tags: ios, autolayout

Just a very direct question, but we had spent many hours trying to find a working solution but faild.

In Xcode, storyboard, how to set a constraint so one view can be located **30% of total window** height from the top of the superview? And we need it to be that way for ALL supported iOS devices of all orientations.

Please see my illustration attached.[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Update

Sorry, I have misunderstood your problem.

You'll need to add the constraints from code like so (the `xConstraint` is totally arbitrary, but you must need to define x, y positions, width and height, for an unambiguous layout):

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: view.bounds.height / 3)

        let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 30)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([yConstraint, xConstraint])
    }
```

This way, the equation will be:

```
imageView.top = 1 * view.top + (view.width / 3)
```

#### Original answer

Auto Layout uses the following equation for constraints:

```
aView.property = Multiplier * bView.property + Constant
```

Based on this, you can simply add an equal width/height constraint, then add a multiplier:

[image]

So the equation will be:

```
view.height = 0.3 * superView.height + 0
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `view.top` instead of `view.height` ? You can't write this kind of constraint (relating two different properties) in IB, you have to do them in code.

Comment: Thanks!! It looks doable, but, it's my fault, I should say it's better that can be done without coding...You see, we had a general rule, a silly one, that everything UI related should be in the storyboard unless it's 100% necessary. So what I'm looing for is a solution, maybe by adding some nested UIViews? I mean I can do it in HTML using nothing but CSS, why can't we do it in storyboard? I really think we can...

Comment: Well, in that case just add a `UIView` which is pinned to the top layout guide, with the height that is the 1/3 of the superview's height (just like I explained originally), and an invisible background color. And add your image view below it, with 0 distance.

Comment: I know it's only a workaround, but I don't believe the constraint itself is possible without some code (just as @Cyrille pointed out).

Comment: I know it now. It seems you are correct. I'm closing this thread and giving you the credit. Still thinking it's quite common and maybe Apple will add this to the future build of xcode. Thank you guys!!

Answer (score 19):

I demonstrate this below - you just have to change the value of multiplier. [image][image]

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer

Comment: Just to elaborate: each constraint is a linear function of the form 'pos=multiplier*SECOND_ITEM + constant', so if you need your view 40% from the left of the parent view, select **trailing** as your 'SECOND_ITEM', set **constant** to 0, and set **multiplier** to 0.4. This will give 'pos=0.4*TRAILING+0' which is 40% of the trailing distance (width). Do similar for vertical positioning...

Answer (score 2):

You should calculate it.

**1.** Calculate how many percents are from top to center ImageView

**2.** Set Vertical center to ImageView

**3.** Configure multiplier in Vertical center constraint and set multiplier from **1**

For example: multiplier 0.5 will be 25% from top to center ImageView. So your multiplier will be ~0.6

By the way, there is another way how to do it:

**1.** Create transparent view from top to your imageView

**2.** Set height equal to your subview

**3.** Set multiplier to 0.3 to this height constraint

**4.** Set bottom space from your imageView to this transparent view equal to zero

Answer (score 2):

To avoid having to recalculate a constant each time after `layoutSubviews`, use `UILayoutGuide`.

Create a layout guide equal to 30% of the view's height, and then use that to align the top of the child view. No manual layout calculations necessary.

```
// Create a layout guide aligned with the top edge of the parent, with a height equal to 30% of the parent
let verticalGuide = UILayoutGuide()
parent.addLayoutGuide(verticalGuide)
verticalGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.topAnchor).isActive = true
verticalGuide.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.3).isActive = true

// Align the top of the child to the bottom of the guide
child.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

`UILayoutGuide` can be laid out with constraints like any view, but doesn't appear in the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Equal Heights Constraint` properties pane, you set the multiplier to "1:3" (i.e. 30% in division notation).

Comment: It's not the *height* of the view that should be 1/3 of the height of its parent, it's its *top margin* that should be 1/3 of the *height* of the parent. Undoable in IB.

Comment: I read it too fast. And in fact, we reach very quickly the limits of IB when building more adaptable interfaces. That's why I prefer define my interfaces in code.

Comment: equal heights constraint is disabled on me, anything Im missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is Simple Solution if you want to give Constraint according to Screen.

[To Set Height Percentage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sMvu.png)

[To Set Width Percentage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsNtK.png)

```
import UIKit

extension NSLayoutConstraint{
    
    /// Set Constant as per screen Width Percentage
    @IBInspectable var widthPercentage:CGFloat {
        set {
            self.constant = (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * newValue)/100
        }
        get {
            return self.constant
        }
    }
    
    /// Set Constant as per screen Height Percentage
    @IBInspectable var heightPercentage:CGFloat {
        set {
            self.constant = (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height * newValue)/100
        }
        get {
            return self.constant
        }
    }
}
```